# Recreating strncpy()

Tags: c, string, while-loop, char

I have an assignment where I have to recreate the strlcpy function from C without any libraries. I wrote the code and submitted it, but it was marked as wrong. Do you know why?

I've attached the diff text I was given that represents why I got the question wrong (it looks like gibberish to me) and a solution two of my peers put that was marked as correct. Can you tell when the two functions might ever have different outputs?

I've asked many of my peers in addition to ChatGPT 3.5 and 4.0 and ClaudeAI. The AI's initially said that the functions were different, but were all unable to give any input that would result in a different outcome.
My Code:

```
char    *ft_strncpy(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int    i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        if (src[i])
            dest[i] = src[i];
        else
            dest[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    return (dest);
}
```

Peers' Code:

```
{
        unsigned int    i;
        i = 0;
        while (i < n && src[i] !='\0')
        {
                dest[i] = src[i];
                i++;
        }
        while (i < n)
        {
                dest[i] = '\0';
                i++;
        }
        return (dest);
}
```

I'll out the diff text in a comment so it doesn't take up so much space

```
$> diff -U 3 user_output_test1 test1.output | cat -e
--- user_output_test1 2024-03-20 15:16:50.490408519 +0000$
+++ test1.output 2024-03-20 15:16:50.470408242 +0000$
@@ -2,69 +2,69 @@$
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d6b4c6156524a4e4f64505a6d62724d$
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d6b4c61524256466c575441675a444f$
```

Comment: Start of diff file (The text is much much longer):
$> diff -U 3 user_output_test1 test1.output | cat -e
--- user_output_test1   2024-03-20 15:16:50.490408519 +0000$
+++ test1.output        2024-03-20 15:16:50.470408242 +0000$
@@ -2,69 +2,69 @@$
 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d6b4c6156524a4e4f64505a6d62724d$
 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d6b4c61524256466c575441675a444f$

Comment: `strncpy` or `strlcpy`?

Comment: In any case, your function reads past the end of `src`.

Comment: Don't forget that `strncpy()` does not provide a terminating nul character if the buffer is full.

Comment: `strncpy` is a function used for fixed-width strings in ancient Unix. `strlcpy` is a non-standard function for copying a fixed length of a C string. They don't do the same thing.

Comment: @WeatherVane In fact it adds no null termination at all, it just zero pads the remaining part of the fixed-width string. Fixed-width strings did not use null termination.

Comment: try this as the source: char src[3] = {0, ' ', 0};

Comment: @lubdin also, *strlcpy* returns something entirely different (a length) than *strncpy* (which returns a pointer) - Which isn't entirely helpful as well...

Comment: This will produce a different result: `char s[] = {'a','b','c','\0','d','e','f'};`. Given `char d[10];`, actual `strncpy()` will put {'a','b','c','\0\,'\0',...,'\0'} into `d[]`, yours will put {'a','b','c','\0','d','e','f', ?? , ?? , ?? }, where "??" is some byte beyond the end of `s[]`, and is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Are you aware, that the `if` part and the `else` part are doing the same thing?

Comment: The `diff`output isn't really helpful. Appreciate the effort, but that's not intended to be read by humans.

Comment: Put material like the diff output in the question, not in a comment.  Or, in this case, omit it altogether because it isn't very helpful at all.  Your code does not properly null pad the string, unlike your peer's code.  Test your colleague's code against yours with a source array `const char source[] = "ABC\0\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF"` and a target array `char target[32] = "";` and specify a length of 16.  When you print a hex dump of the target buffer (at least 16 bytes of it), you will see the differences.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has at least three flaws (the first two are clearly bugs, the last one is just unnecessary code):

1. It reads beyond the source string end (because it always reads at least n bytes from there, even if the source string is shorter)
2. It doesn't (even if the man page clearly says it should) pad the destination buffer with \000 bytes if the source string is shorter than the destination buffer. Instead, it writes random garbage from beyond the source string end.
3. The "if-else"-clause is entirely useless. In the one case where it triggers the `else` (at the terminating NUL) the `else` branch does exactly what the `if` branch would have done. It basically boils down to `dst [i] = src[i];`

Otherwise, your code does *something like* `strncpy()`, but doesn't handle the corner cases as it should. With a bit more experience, you might learn that half-working code (like yours) is even more dangerous than code which is not working at all, because the problems are typically found very late and will only occur spuriously. Just a bit more into that:

Your '`strncpy`' might seem to work work for a long time when your user (who calls the function) is supplying reasonable buffer sizes (n) in comparison with the average string length of the source string. Imagine a very generous user decides to supply 10000 bytes of destination buffer, and your source string is only 60 characters long in a buffer space of 80. That would mean you're reading 9920 bytes beyond your source buffer into potentially unallocated memory, which is very likely to cause a segmentation fault, which will be hard to find (because "it used to work all the time!").

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea how I didn't catch this! I guess I thought that every character after the end of a string would be null, but obviously that's not true.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@tofro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78201846/2410359) good answer,

OP's (and Peers') code has 4 type issues.

```
char *ft_strncpy(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int n);
// vs.
char *strncpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n);
```

- Use `size_t n`.  `unsigned int n` is too narrow for *long* strings.  String length may exceed `UINT_MAX`, but not `SIZE_MAX`.
- Calling `const char *ref = "abc"; ft_strncpy(dest,ref, 3);` leads to a compiler error, but `strncpy(dest,ref, 3)` does not.
- Calling `char s[9] = "abc"; buft_strncpy(s+1, s, 8);` should lead to a compiler warning as the buffers overlap and using `restrict` indicates to a compiler to flag that.
- Pedantic: `src[i] !='\0'` is a problem on exceedingly rare non-2's complement encoding and `char` is *signed* as that stops the loop on +0 and -0.  *String* functions should perform *as if* the characters were `unsigned char`.  "For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value)."

Candidate alternative (akin to "Peers' Code"):

```
char *alt_strncpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n) {
  unsigned char *u1 = (unsigned char *) s1;
  const unsigned char *u2 = (const unsigned char *) s2;

  while (n > 0 && *u2) {
    n--;
    *u1++ = *u2++;
  }

  while (n > 0) {
    n--;
    *u1++ = '\0';
  }

  return s1;
}
```